# Command for killing specific PID provided by previous command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, process, pipe, lsof

Sometimes I need to kill a process (the reasons why are not important). And I know I can find that process with the following command: `lsof -i :8080`, being my candidate the **last process** in the output table.

For example, if I run the command, an output like this will appear:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    15112 dani   70u  IPv4 3178183      0t0  TCP localhost:39998->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    15112 dani  137u  IPv4 3181607      0t0  TCP localhost:39999->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    15112 dani  138u  IPv4 3181608      0t0  TCP localhost:40000->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    15112 dani  139u  IPv4 3181609      0t0  TCP localhost:40001->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    15112 dani  140u  IPv4 3181610      0t0  TCP localhost:40002->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    19509 dani   50u  IPv6 4617361      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
java    19509 dani   52u  IPv6 6642445      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt->localhost:42996 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

So, my target will be that *PID 19509*. Using pipes, how can I cherry-pick last line's PID?

I want to reach a command like `lsof -i :8080 | something here to get the PID | kill -9`

I'm running Linux Mint KDE x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question literally, here's one way to list the last PID displayed by `lsof`:

```
lsof … | awk 'END {print $2}'
```

[Awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a text processing language which reads input and processes it line by line. In the code, `END {…}` executes the code in the braces after the whole input is processed, and effectively operates on the last line. `$2` is the second whitespace-delimited field on the line.

And here are some ways to kill it (each line works on its own):

```
kill $(lsof … | awk 'END {print $2}')
lsof … | awk 'END {print $2}' | xargs kill
lsof … | awk 'END {system("kill " $2)}'
```

However, I dispute your assertion that the right process to kill is always the last one. `lsof` displays processes by increasing PID, which is meaningless. Even on systems where process IDs are assigned sequentially (which is not the case on all Unix variants, not even on all Linux installations), they wrap once they reach the maximum value (commonly 32767). Thus deciding between processes by comparing PIDs is meaningless.

You need some other information to decide which process to kill. Depending on what kind of information you're after and on whether you might have output that contains “weird” characters (like spaces in file or program names), you may use a tool like awk to process the output of `lsof`, or you may use the `-F` option to `lsof` which produces output that's a bit harder to parse in simple cases but (almost) not prone to ambiguity and easier to parse robustly. For example, if you want to kill any process that's listening on port 8080, here's how you can do it:

```
lsof -n -i :8080 -F | awk '
    sub(/^p/,"") {pid = $0}
    $0 == "n*:http-alt" {print pid}
' | xargs kill
```

The call to the `sub` function replaces `p` at the beginning of a line by an empty string. If this replacement is performed, the code block `{pid = $0}` is executed; this way the `pid` variable contains the last PID value displayed by `lsof`. The second awk line prints the value of the `pid` variable if the line is exactly `"n*:http-alt"`, which is lsof's way to report a socket listening on port 8080 on all interfaces.

This particular criterion actually doesn't require any parsing (I only showed it above as an example). You can make `lsof` display just processes listening on the specified port:

```
lsof -n -a -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -Fp | sed 's/^p//' | xargs kill
```

Or, for this, you can use [`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) instead.

```
netstat -lnpt | awk '$4 ~ /:8080$/ {sub(/\/.*/, "", $7); print $7}'
```

Explanation of the awk code: if the 4th column ends with `:8080`, replace everything after the first `/` in the 7th column (to remove the process name part and keep only the PID part), and print it.

Comment: Really complete and extremely usefull answer. I really appreciate the verbosity. After reading all the alternatives you gave me, I chose the `lsof -n -a -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -Fp | sed 's/^p//' | xargs kill`. It seems to be the most accurate for my purposes. Also, in my simple mind there is a meaning for that process to be always at the bottom of the table: Is a process which is started/stoped very often and, sometimes, crashes (and then I need to kill it), so in most cases will be the last in the table. But, also, I take'll take into account the maximum of 32767 PID numbers, as you said.